# Unable to install the iOS (enterprise distribution) app on global devices but able install it from Testflight mode

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, app-distribution

I have generated the distribute app with distribution provisioning profile.

I'm able to install it from Testflight but I'm unable to install the build on global devices.

Comment: give more info on how you install the app

Comment: Regualr procedure..From Xcode , I just Archived the project with distribution  profile and installing the app through iTunes...

Comment: What do you mean by global devices?  Are you using an app store distribution profile?  If so, you can't install that directly on a device - you can only install through Testflight or the App Store.

Comment: Yes im using appstore distribution profile and Global devices means, diveces which are not included in developer account. In my organization we have many devices and few are not listed in apple development account. For testing purpose  we need to install  the app in all devices . Please guide me how to install the build on global devices directly  not through TestFlight. Also provide any valuable forum links

Comment: You need to create an In House Distribution profile and use that to sign the app for distribution to company devices.

Comment: Take device logs, there is info why it happened